# Is it possible to do regex(case insensitive) in rethinkdb getAll?

Tags: rethinkdb

I know that in `rethinkdb` you can `filter` and `match` for `regex` but is there any way to do `getAll` and put regex into value? I know that you are searching for particular value with `getAll` in index but it would be great if you can do something like this:

```
r.db("db").table("table").getAll(/value/i, {index:"index"})
```

I am asking this because of this query for example:

```
r.db("db").table("table").getAll("Bern", {index:"city"}) -- >> will give results

r.db("db").table("table").getAll("bern", {index:"city"}) -- >> will not give results
```

Comment: good question. I think there is nothing like that in getAll query. 
You can ask in slack community where you can get your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by creating a secondary index for `city` in lower case:

```js
r.db("db").table("table").indexCreate('lowercity', r.row('city').downcase())
```

Then perform `getAll()` by this index:

```js
r.db("db").table("table").getAll("bern", {index:"lowercity"}) // will now produce results
```